# Different graphs for the same equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $y^2=x$ and $y=x^{0.5}$ the same thing?

It appears so but when I plotted the graph in a graph plotting app it seemed to be different. 
In the first equation gives a complete parabola but second one gives a half parabola.  Can anyone explain this intuitively.

Comment: $(1,-1)$ satisfies $x=y^2$ but not $\sqrt{x}=y.$

Comment: Can you give some algebric proof or some domain range sort of thing

Comment: @mfl You are right but I think you should stay consistent which variable is on which side, for greater clarity: $$(x,y) = (1,-1)\,\, \text{ satisfies }\,\, x=y^2 \,\text{ ,} \, \text{ but not } \,\sqrt{x} = y$$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Done. Thank you for suggesting it.

Answer (score 2):

These are not the same thing. We have
$$(1)\qquad y^2=x\\(2)\qquad y=x^{0.5}$$
Notice that $(1)$ can have $y$ values less than $0$ (i.e. $y$ can be negative). However, for $(2)$, $y$ cannot have negative values, because $x^{0.5}\geq 0$ for any $x\in\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$. You can think of $(1)$ as a sideways parabola. Where a "standard" parabola would be something like $y=x^2$, you can think of $(1)$ as a parabola like $x=y^2$, which is a parabola with $y$ as the independent variable. However, $(2)$ is not a full sideways parabola, but rather a "half sideways parabola", because it does not permit negative $y$ values (like a parabola $y=x^2$ but only defined on $[0,\infty)$).

When you rearrange for $y$ in $(1)$ you would end up with the following: 
$$y^2=x\implies y=\pm x^{0.5}$$
where $y=\pm x^{0.5}$ and $y^2=x$ would yield the same graph.

Comment: Thanks friend it was very helpful